# Footer-bar won't go at bottom of page

Tags: html, css, footer

I tried everything now. My footer-bar keeps staying in the middle of the page or fixed on the bottom of the screen. I need it on the bottom of the page, no matter how much content I put on the website.

```css
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bottom : auto, instead of '0'

```css
#footer {
position: absolute;
right: 0;
bottom: auto;
left: 0;
width:100%;
height:60px;
background:#000000;
}
```

```html
content <br>Content<br>Content
<div id="footer">

</div>
```

Comment: Still at middle of page.

Comment: if you just want the footer to follow your content, then remove all the properties `position` `right` `left` `bottom`

Comment: It doesn't have any effect.